# Newtonsoft Json serialize a class where one of the properties is JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Newtonsoft Json serialization (with Web API 2).

One of the public properties on my class is a String that holds JSON data. I'd like to serialize my class, and include this public property, but I don't want the serializer to process/modify the contents of this string.

Is there any way I can include this property, but not mess with its contents?